# How do I get light to go through a window texture in Unity?

Tags: unity, lighting

I'm having trouble with the lighting (I have windows and the light wont go through). How do I get the light to proceed through the glass?

Comment: try this... it's a video tutorial I made for glass using free assets http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXNv9EPHyHw

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach different materials on transparent and opaque objects. Then, if you assign a transparent shader to transparent surfaces, the light will go through. Another approach could be detaching glasses on the modeling program, create and assign some other layer for the glass parts and have the light ignore that layer.